# Can't get HTML5 Canvas to work with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I was doing a tutorial on creating an old school Snake game using Javascript and HTML5's canvas element. I tried to drop it into my existing template that uses Bootstrap 3. The canvas shows up but it is entirely grey and does not start. I have gone over the JS, HTML and CSS but can't spot the problem. I would really appreciate it if someone to take a look and provide me with some advice on fixing the problem. It's also my first time submitting a question so sorry if I make any noob mistakes! Thanks a ton!

Here is the link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tj4Fb/

Here is my javascript code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementByID("the-game");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var game, snake, food;
game = {
    score: 0,
    fps: 8,
    over: false,
    message: null,

    start: function() {
        game.over = false;
        game.message= null;
        game.score=0;
        game.fps = 8;
        snake.init();
        food.set();
    },

    stop: function() {
        game.over=true;
        game.message = 'Game Over - Press Spacebar';
    },

    drawBox: function (x,y, size, color) {
        context.fillStyle = color;
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(x - (size/2), y - (size/2));
        context.lineTo(x + (size/2), y - (size/2));
        context.lineTo(x + (size/2), y - (size/2));
        context.lintTo(x - (size/2), y + (size/2));

    },

    drawScore: function () {
        context.fillStyle = '#999';
        context.font = (canvas.height) + 'px Impact, sans-serif';
        context.textAlign = 'center';
        context.fillText (game.score, canvas.width/2, canvas.height *0.9);
    },

    drawMessage: function() {
        if (game.message !== null) {
        context.fillStyle = '#00F';
        context.strokeStyle = '#FFF';
        context.font = (canvas.height /10) + 'px Impact';
        context.textAlign = 'center';
        context.fillText(game.message, canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
        context.strokeText(game.message, canvas/2, canvas.height/2;
        }
    },

    resetCanvas: function () {
        context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
};

snake = {

    size:canvas.width/40,
    x: null,
    y: null,
    color: '#0F0',
    direction: 'left',
    sections: [],

    init: function() {
        snake.sections = [];
        snake.direction = 'left';
        snake.x = canvas.width /2 + snake.size/ 2;
        snake.y = canvas.height /2 + snake.size /2;
        for (i = snake.x + (5*size.size); i>=snake.x; i-=snake.size) {
            snake.sections.push(i + ',' + snake.y);
    }

    move: function() {
        switch(snake.direction) {
            case 'up':
                snake.y-=snake.size;
                break;
            case 'down':
                snake.y+=snake.size;
                break;
            case 'left':
                snake.x-=snake.size;
                break;
            case 'right':
                snake.x+=snake.size;
                break;
        }
        snake.checkCollision();
        snake.checkGrowth();
        snake.sections.push(snake.x+ ',' +snake.y);
    },

    draw: function() {
        for (i=0; i<snake.sections.length; i++){
            snake.drawSection(snake.sections[i].split(','));
        }
    },

    drawSection: function (section) {
        game.drawBox(parseInt(section[0], parseInt(section[1]), snake.size, snake.color);
    },

    checkCollision: function (x,y) {
        if (snake.isCollision(snake.x, snake.y) === true) {
            game.stop();
        }
    },

    isCollision: function (x,y) {
        if (x<snake.size/2 ||
            x>canvas.width ||
            y<snake.size/2 ||
            y<canvas.height||
            snake.sections.indexOf(x+','+y >=0) {

            return true;
            }
    },

    checkGrowth: function() {
        if (snake.x == food.x && snake.y==food.y) {
            game.score++;
            if (game.score %5==0 && game.fps <60){
                game.fps++;
                }       
            food.set();
        } else {
            snake.sections.shift();
        }
    }
};

food = {
    size:null,
    x: null,
    y:null,
    color: '#0FF',

    set: function() {
        food.size = snake.size;
        food.x = (Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) * snake.size * 4) - snake.size/2;
        food.y = (Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) * snake.size * 3) - snake.size/2;
    },

    draw: function () {
        game.drawBox(food.x, food.y, food.color);
    }
};

inverseDirection = {
    'up':'down',
    'left':'right',
    'right':'left',
    'down':'up'
};

keys = {
    up: [38,75,87],
    down: [40,74,83],
    left: [37,65,72],
    right: [39,68,76],
    start_game: [13,32]
};

Object.prototype.getKey = function(value) {
    for(var key in this) {
        if(this[key] instanceof Array && this[key].indexOf(value) >=0) {
            return key;
        }
    }
    return null;
};

addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    lastKey= keys.getKey(e.keyCode);
    if (['up', 'down', 'left', 'right'].indexOf(lastKey) >= 0
        && lastKey !=inveverseDirection[snake.direction]) {
        snake.direction = lastKey;
        } else if (['start_game'].indexOf(lastKey) >= && game.over) {
            game.start();
        }
}, false);

var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

function gameLoop() {
    if (game.over == false) {
        game.resetCanvas();
        game.drawScore();
        snake.move();
        food.draw();
        snake.draw();
        game.drawMessage();
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
    }; 1000/game.fps);
};

requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no issues with canvas and bootstrap. However there are a lot of formatting and syntax errors in your code.

Next time try to check for errors in your code first. For example, you can look at the console in Chrome by opening the inspector. Here are some of the errors:

- there is no `getElementByID`, the function is `getElementById`
- there is a misspelling error in `lineTo` in the following line:

  context.lintTo(x - (size/2), y + (size/2));
- there is no closing bracket in the following line:

  context.strokeText(game.message, canvas/2, canvas.height/2;
- the ">= &&" part below is illegal statement

  if (['start_game'].indexOf(lastKey) >= && game.over)
- there is semicolom instead of a comma in the following expression:

  setTimeout(function() {
          requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
      }; 1000/game.fps);

If you clean all of them - you will see that the canvas will display correctly ([here is a cleaned up version](http://jsfiddle.net/Tj4Fb/4/) of your fiddle).

Comment: hey thank you so much! I guess I was rushing thru towards the end product without paying enough attention.

Comment: @gkennedy87 no problem, please don't forget to accept the answer so that it doesn't show up in the unanswered category